# XX-XX-XX (e.g. 11-12-B4, 11-12-F3, etc.) RAM information. What does it mean?

Tags: memory

I've seen RAMs having numbers in the format XX-XX-XX, like 11-12-B4 or 11-12-F3.
What do these numbers signify? I'm not able to find information as to what do these numbers mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those numbers separated by dashes are usually memory timings:
1) CAS Latency - how much before RAM reacts to anything
2) Row Address To Column Address Delay (tRCD) - delay between memory row and column access
3) Row Precharge Time (tRP) - how much latency to select a new row
4) Row Active Time (tRAS) - how many cycles before you can read

Sometimes you will see all of them, sometimes just a few (generally first two).

In your examples, only first two fields are timings (CAS=11, tRCD=12). Third one (F3/B4) seems just as a manufacturer's reference.

There is quite nice [YouTube video (How Do Memory Timings Work?)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yed-a9vqTYc) explaining timings in details.

If you have specific memory you want to check, usually it is much better finding it on manufacturer's site using full part number and checking specification there.